# Trouble passing a PHP variable from my index page to my upload script

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to pass a URL pram "link" over a variable to my upload script. I'm having a lot of trouble debugging the issue and am not having any luck passing it over on post to upload.php. Any help or advice would be very appreciated. The first bit of code is my index.php which should always come with a URL parm such as '?link=9288'.

example https://exampledomain.com/videos/?link=9288

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
    $_SESSION['varname'] = $_GET['link'];
?>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "../../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is a Video- " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 400000000000000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "webm" && $imageFileType != "mpg" && $imageFileType != "mpeg" && $imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "m4p" && $imageFileType != "m4v" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "wmv" && $imageFileType != "mov" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only WEBM, MPG, MPEG, MP4, M4P, M4V, AVI, WMV, MOV files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
echo $var_value;
?>
```

Comment: Have you started the session before you're using it? If you want the data in `$_SESSION` to be persistent, you need to have `start_session();` before it, both before you read or write to the session. If not, the data won't persist between calls.

Comment: In this case, why not just add a hidden input into the form with the link instead? Something like: `<input type="hidden" name="link" value="<?= $_GET['link'] ?? '' ?>">`. Then you should be able to get the value with `$_POST['link']` in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Before you Read and Write A Session You must start session_start(); (Both Page) ,
I hope Its Solve Your Problem